# conda: how to turn channel URLs online

Tags: python, anaconda, runtime-error, conda, arcgis

For my Bachelor-Thesis I have to work with conda for ArcGIS Pro but I am a bloody rookie.
When I try anything like installing new packages or even just cloning an environment I get an Error back. E.g.:

```
(arcgispro-py3) F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3>conda create --name deeplearning --clone arcgispro-py3
Source:      F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3
Destination: F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\deeplearning
Packages: 126
Files: 16

CondaError: RuntimeError('EnforceUnusedAdapter called with url https://conda.anaconda.org/esri/win-64/arcgispro-2.5-0.tar.bz2\nThis command is using a remote connection in offline mode.\n',)
CondaError: RuntimeError('EnforceUnusedAdapter called with url https://conda.anaconda.org/esri/win-64/arcgispro-2.5-0.tar.bz2\nThis command is using a remote connection in offline mode.\n',)
CondaError: RuntimeError('EnforceUnusedAdapter called with url https://conda.anaconda.org/esri/win-64/arcgispro-2.5-0.tar.bz2\nThis command is using a remote connection in offline mode.\n',)
```

With `conda info` I found out that all my channel URLs are set offline. I guess my problems come from that issue. So: How can I set them online again?
I tried reinstalling ArcGIS and all related Programs several times but it didn't help.

CONDA INFO:

```
(arcgispro-py3) F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3>conda info
Current conda install:

               platform : win-64
          conda version : 4.3.27
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.27
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.6.8.final.0
       requests version : 2.22.0
       root environment : F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python  (writable)
    default environment : F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3
       envs directories : F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python\envs
                          C:\Users\Niko\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Niko\.conda\envs
          package cache : C:\Users\Niko\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\pkgs
                          F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python\pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch  (offline)
                          https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/win-64  (offline)
                          https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/noarch  (offline)
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/new_channel/win-64  (offline)
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/new_channel/noarch  (offline)
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/esri/win-64  (offline)
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/esri/noarch  (offline)
            config file : F:\Programme\ArcGIS\bin\Python\.condarc
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : True
             user-agent : conda/4.3.27 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.6.8 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
```

Trying to set the offline mode to false with `conda config --set offline false` did not work. The command just gets ignored.

---

**FIX:**
Command `conda config --set offline false` works in the base environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have triggered **Offline Mode** in Anaconda Navigator (see [Offline Mode documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/overview/#offline-mode)), which can toggle based on whether or not an internet connection is detected.. It can also be manually toggled from the command line, e.g., you could disable it with:

```
conda config --set offline false
```